# How to write bulk updates from a Scrapy pipeline to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I have a continuously running crawler based on Scrapy.

In each run this crawler executes requests on a list of given ids and writes the output to S3 bucket.

These requests might fail from time to time and I need to log the successes and failures.

I'm currently yielding an item on sucess and a special ErrorItem on failure.

I made a Pipeline that should handle the success and failure logging.

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):
    if isinstance(item, MyErrorItem):
        self.errors.append(item['id'])
        raise DropItem('Dropped')
    else:
        self.success.append(item['id'])
        return item

def close_spider(self, spider):
    conn_to_mongo = getconn()
    errors_query = create_or_query_by_ids(self.errors)
    write_to_mongo(errors_query, {"$set": {"status": "fail"}})
    success_query = create_or_query_by_ids(self.success)
    write_to_mongo(success_query, {"$set": {"status": "success"}})
```

I didn't find any reference to this kind of pattern. Usually all writes to external data engines is made from the process_item function.

Here I'm collecting the ids to corresponding lists and writing in bulk on close_spider.

The reason is that it is no efficient to perform multiple write requests to the DB, if this can be done in bulk.

Is there a more efficient wat to achieve this behavior?
Are there any pitfalls with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a big problem with this approach. Some downsides I can think of:

- You keep 2 lists in memory that keep growing while the spider is running. If the lists get big, this can become problematic. If you do the inserts item by item, you wouldn't have this.
- If you have an error with the inserts at the end, you will lose all of the data you have scraped. If, for example, the database is unavailable or overloaded at the moment you want to insert your data, you have to run the spider again

I think a better approach could be the following:

- The item pipeline writes to a json file instead of appending to a list
- At close spider you do an insert based on the json-file instead of from the list

This way you don't overload the memory, and if the insert at the end fails, you can retry it based on the file instead of having to rerun everything again.

Comment: You can flush these lists from time to time. That is at the beginning of `process_item` method check if `len(self.success)` is more than chosen bulk size (50 or 100 items). And if so - write it to db and clean the list